# Character-wise accuracy for image-to-text models

Tags: nlp, cnn, computer-vision, transformer, ocr

is it possible to enforce image-to-text models like ViT or a simple CNN+Transformer to achieve character-wise accuracy?

Here's the context of my project:
I am developing a model to extract some targeted phrases and numbers from individual pdf pages and I would like the numbers, especially, to be character wise accurate.

Correct me if I am wrong, but ViT or other CNN+Transformer models make context-based estimations which is not the same as character-wise estimation, am I right?

One idea that I have is to tokenize the ground truth string on a character level instead of word but I am not sure how feasible this is.